# cygwin : Linker doesn't find shared library

Tags: cygwin

I am creating an exe and shared library in cygwin.

The library is created and is in the proper place, but when I try to compile the client code daemon, the linking phase says that it can't find the sysutil library.

Error is posted below:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lsysutil
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:84: daemon] Error 1
```

I tried exporting the path using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but unfortunately that also didn't help.

daemon.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys_util.h>

int main(){

    sys_util();
    while(1){

    }
    return 0;
}
```

sysutil.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sys_util.h"

int sys_util(){

        return 0;
}
```

sysutil.h

```
int sys_util();
```

test.bat

```
g++ -fpic -c sysutil.c
g++ -shared -o libsysutil.so sysutil.o -I.

g++ -c daemon.c -I.
g++ -o daemon.exe daemon.o -L. -lsysutil
del *.o
```

Shared library is generated sysutil.so in the folder c:/test same as the source code (daemon.c,sysutil.c,sys_util.h,test.bat,libsysutil.so)

Cygwin console output:
/cygdrive/c/test
$ ./test.bat

C:\test>g++ -fpic -c sysutil.c
sysutil.c:1:0: warning: -fpic ignored for target (all code is position independent)

C:\test>g++ -shared -o libsysutil.so sysutil.o -I.

C:\test>g++ -c daemon.c -I.

C:\test>g++ -o daemon.exe daemon.o -L. -lsysutil
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsysutil
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

C:\test>del *.o

Comment: Where is the import library and how you are calling the compiler ? You gave us no info to guess where is the problem

Comment: @matzeri I have updated the sample code and console linking error.

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin expects shared libraries to have the .dll extension.

Change the second line in your batch file to:

```
g++ -shared -o sysutil.dll sysutil.o -I.
```

See the users' guide for more info:
  https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html